# Simulate enter press in windows 8.1 store application

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, multiline

I have a windows 8.1 store application. Within this application I'm trying to simulate the enter/return key press on a button click event. The control that I'm changing is a XAML Multi-Line TextBox.

So I enter the text 'The' in the Textbox.

I then press my button to simulate the enter click. The code for this is:

```
textBox.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}", textBox.Text, Environment.NewLine);
```

so the text is now 'The\r\n'.

I now set the selection start to be at the end. so:

```
textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
```

at this point SelectionStart is now 4 and the textbox.Text.Length is 5 (Zero based so OK)

I now enter append the word 'one' to the textbox. so now then text is now 'The\r\none'

I now use my button to simulate the enter key again.

The text is now 'The\r\none\r\n' and the text.length is 10.

I now try to set the selectionStart position using the same code as above:

```
textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
```

However the SelectionStart = 8 even though the Text.length=10;

So now when I enter another character it goes before the carriage return. e.g.

textbox.Text now equals 'The\r\nonez\r\n'. 'z' is the newly entered character.

Does anybody know why this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0);
```

Source :
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752349(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752349%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The same thing happens